# Software distribution

Tags: file-server

I want to distribute my software, and I want to know what is the best way to do it.

My software is an `.exe` file that uses two `dll` files, so what I want to distribute is just an `.zip` file where thoose files can stay.

What I want, is like a cloud to my files can reside and users can download it by entering the credentials that I give them.

Finally, it would be great that I can see how much people had downloaded my software and some statistics like, number of downloads, where it has been downloaded …

Anyone knows a software, platform cloud etc. for me? I use Atlassian solutions for other parts (like issues management or code deployment), but I can't find a specific solution for this case.

Comment: "how much people had downloaded my software and some statistics like, number of downloads, where it has been downloaded" I think you'd better to publish your software at your own host.

Comment: Are you OK with creating people's accounts manually? Or requiring people to create an account on a third-party platform and then adding them manually? Or do you need a more automatic solution? Also, what is your budget?

Comment: I've founded JFrog Bintray for this issue